# Auto-refresh of prompt-toolkit fullscreen app

Tags: python, prompt-toolkit

I'm trying to get a bit into prompt-toolkit for building CLI apps. Maybe it's a trivial question, but I could not find any solution in the docs or in other posts.

I want to build a full-screen app with prompt-toolkit, that monitors and displays periodically changing information. As a demonstrator, I just wanted to display the current date and time, and have it update every second.

However, I could not yet find any way for a prompt-toolkit app to update itself without user input. I assume, I need to add some callback somewhere, but the documentation is not very clear on that and I have not found a good example yet.

---

**Update 1:**
After some more trial&error I found that the following code produces the expected result, although I'm still not a 100% sure if this is the best way of doing it.

With `app.create_background_task()` one can add coroutines that to the event loop. In this example I update the text in the upper part of the window. However, this does not do anything, unless the user manually refreshes the app (I think with `app.invalidate()`) OR by providing the `refresh` argument in `Application`.

I think this solution is sufficient unless too much other stuff is happening so that the refresh-rate cannot be maintained..

```py
import datetime
import asyncio

from prompt_toolkit import Application
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding import KeyBindings
from prompt_toolkit.layout.containers import Window, HSplit
from prompt_toolkit.layout.controls import FormattedTextControl
from prompt_toolkit.layout.layout import Layout
from prompt_toolkit import widgets


static_text = FormattedTextControl(text=f"Time: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}")
static_window = Window(content=static_text, height=2)

telemetry_window = Window(content=FormattedTextControl(text="Some fixed text"))

root_container = HSplit([
    widgets.Frame(body=static_window),
    widgets.Frame(body=telemetry_window)
])

layout = Layout(root_container)

kb = KeyBindings()


@kb.add('c-q')
@kb.add('c-c')
def exit_(event):
    event.app.exit()


app = Application(layout=layout, full_screen=True, key_bindings=kb, refresh_interval=0.5)


async def refresh():
    while True:
        static_text.text = f"Time: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}"
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


app.create_background_task(refresh())
app.run()
```

---

**Update 2:**

It's also possible to update text controls through running threads. Every time the UI is invalidated, it renders itself with the new values set to text. So, a coroutine is not strictly necessary.

Comment: where do you want to update it? In line with prompt? In some place on screen? It may need to run code in separated `thread`. maybe better show `minimal working code`.

Comment: Added an update with a code example. So since it's a full-screen app, I just wanted to demonstrate automatic updates in one part of the window and the rest does whatever (be static, update something else, wait for user input, etc.)

So I guess I answered my own question, but I'd be very happy to hear about alternatives or improvements.

Comment: found with Google: [Dynamically updating prompt · Issue #1286 · prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/issues/1286) and there is link to example [clock-input.py](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/examples/prompts/clock-input.py). You can also try to check in source code how `prompt()` executes this function with interval.

Comment: Yea I found this as well after posting my initial question. Based on this I then managed to find a solution for a full screen app

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [Application](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/reference.html#module-prompt_toolkit.application) shows:

```
refresh_interval – Automatically invalidate the UI every so many seconds. 
When None (the default), only invalidate when invalidate has been called.
```

and it also shows:

```
on_invalidate – Called when the UI has been invalidated.
```

It automatically runs `refresh` when I assign it to `on_invalidate=`

```
def refresh(app):
    #print(app)
    static_text.text = f"Time: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}"

app = Application(..., refresh_interval=0.5, on_invalidate=refresh)
```

or to `before_render=`

```
def refresh(app):
    #print(app)
    static_text.text = f"Time: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}"

app = Application(..., refresh_interval=0.5, before_render=refresh)
```

Comment: Yep! Both are nice options. I guess for me it was initially a bit weird to understand what "invalidating" means. But by now it's clearer.